# How i can clone wordpress site urls only to new one?

Tags: wordpress, url, copy

how to copy wordpress site structure  to new  wordpress site  , i need to clone all pages urls with blank content  and no media files to the new one.

All plugins for migration copy sites urls with content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup first your copy site and after setup you clone site you got to you post table and the execute the below query

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name] = NULL;
```

After you page content will blank and then you can delete images/other files which is numbered or related that.

Comment: Sorry ,  i  beginner with  sql database  , i tried navigate to   database in my phpadmin   ----->  wp_posts  ----.>  sql    ------> then   UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name] = NULL and run  it gives me errors

Comment: Solved , if i run  query  UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content  =  NULL it returns error   ----> column 'post_content' cannot be null   ,,, the query worked fine if i run   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content  = ''   ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,  thanks  Anjan for your help

Comment: You plz accept the answer for review others.